Inconsistent Vertical Spacing of Text in Beamer With Frametitle
Apologises in advance if this question has already been asked somewhere, but I am working with the following basic template and would like consistent placement of the main body of text in a frame, regardless of whether or not there is a frame title. Notice that inserting a frame title pushes the main body of text down the page, which I do not want to happen.
How do I suppress this effect so that inserting the frame title will not affect the vertical position of the main body of the text?
A minimal working example is given below, and you can see that "Some content." gets pushed down the page by insertion of the "Contents" frame title. I'd like this effect to be completely suppressed for all slides, so the main body of text remains in the same position as before and does not get 'bumped down' when I give each slide, or a selection of the slides, a title.
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \centering
    \Huge \bfseries Your Presentation Title
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[c]
Some content. 
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}[c]{Contents}
Some content.
\end{frame}

\end{document}


The content is centred vertically in the text block because you've told Beamer to do that (c). but your example is very unrealistic. it 'jumps' because the contents of the two frames are identical except for the title, but that isn't something you'd have in a real presentation. sometimes you want the same content (or partly the same), but you don't generally want distinct frames in that case. instead you put them on different slides in a single frame. what exactly is your concern here?

themes such as Berkeley use a fixed height box for the title of frames. you could use that in conjunction with t aligned content, remove the sidebars etc. if you don't want them and change the colours back to defaults or your preferred hues. but this does not eliminate slight variation between frames with empty and substantive titles.

@cfr you could add a \strut to the title template.

@skillmon this isn't really what I'm looking for. I'm happy with the vertical positioning of text on untitled slides and don't want that shifting down to match titled ones. I'd just like the insertion of a frame title not to affect the main body of text if I wanted to change an untitled slide to a titled one.

@wrb98 in that case you'd have to ignore the title's height, which might result in overprinting on slides with more contents. I'd strongly advise against that.

@Skillmon overprinting would be easier for me to deal with. I'd be happy for you to provide a solution that achieves what I'm looking for

@wrb98 you need to change the beamer template for title to \smash whatever you give as a title, that way the title's size will no longer be considered, though this might break more placements than you're currently aware of and you should thoroughly test the results. But I'm not going to code this (sorry, limited time and resources).

but you will still have text starting at different heights because slides with more content will push the first line of text up relative to ones with less. so, if you're concerned about 'jumping', simply ignoring the title won't do anything unless you ensure the height and depth of content is identical for all frames.

Assuming your frametitle only has one line and you don't use subtitles, you could try this quick hack:
\documentclass[10pt,c]{beamer}

\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\vskip-0.8cm}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some content.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Contents}
Some content.
\end{frame}

\end{document}


Don't put too much text in such a frame, it will overlap the frame title. Also don't use top aligned frames with this.

Personally, I'd rather use the approach of the sidebar outer theme and push the text down on all frames, regardless of a title:
\documentclass{beamer}

\useoutertheme[width=0pt]{sidebar}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\vskip-0.2em}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some content.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
Some content.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Some content.
\end{frame}

\end{document}


